# Create a dataframe with names from a text

Tags: dataframe, text

I am quite new to R and Quanteda. I'm trying to create a dataframe with people who voted in favour and against a legislative proposal based on parliamentary transcripts. I can't figure out how to do this and some help would be greatly appreciated.

The following is an example of what the text could look like:

*In favour: van Vliet, Nolens, Bruinmelkanip, Krap, Travagliuo and Lucasse.
Those voted against: Verhey, ter Laan, van Gijn, PÜnacker Hordijk, Röell. Troelstra, Drucker, Schaper en Fox.*

I want to try to write it as a function so I can indicate the starting and the ending word of each section and then make the dataframe with all names. If it is a function I could analyse multiple such pieces of text.

Thank you!

Comment: Dear user, could you post some code to illustrate how were you trying to solve a problem, what the problem you are facing and what is the expecting output. In this case it is much easier to help.

Comment: I haven't gotten further than loading the text into R unfortunately.

The results should look something like this:
> x <- data.frame("favor" = c("Van Vliet",Bruinmelkanip"), "against" =  c("Verhey","ter Laan"))